# IGRAPH Python - How to find source code of modularity?

Tags: python, igraph

Ok, so IGRAPH is open source. That means I should be able to find the source code where they compute the modularity of a partition. But I've been searching in their site and the best I could find is some comments explaining how they did it, but no code (https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-pysrc.html#GraphBase.modularity line 820). Am I blind or their implementation isn't avaliable on their site?

Comment: Whats the question? `return GraphBase.modularity(self, membership, weights)` => lookup `GraphBase`

Comment: Yes exactly but we're already in GraphBase's page. So the button "GraphBase" redirects us to the page we're already seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GraphBase` class is not defined in the Python code, but in a [C extension](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/src/_igraph/igraphmodule.c#L784) wrapping the igraph library.

You can find the implementation of the [`modularity` method](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/src/_igraph/graphobject.c#L11149) in `igraph/src/community.c`, e.g. on GitHub:

https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/98969b233d1d97a2dc271fac0036394d2abdaa3c/src/community.c#L907

Comment: Thank you very much. Out of curiosity, how did you discover that? I couldn't find anywhere in the site this information

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I first found it. I searched around the source code on GitHub until I found some clues and traced them.